# Returning data from service dependancy using promises causes $digest iteration error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I have two services where one needs to query the other by an id for example.

This is what I currently have but I'm getting $digest iteration limits.

> "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>   Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

**Controller**

```
angular.module('exampleApp')
.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope, PeopleService, PlanService) {

    $scope.plan = new Plan();
    // or
    $scope.plan = Plan.get({ id: 1 });

    // Used to populate a <select> menu in the view
    PeopleService.all().then(function(data) {
        $scope.people = data;
    });

});
```

**PlanService**

```
angular.module('exampleApp')
.factory('PlanService', function($resource, PeopleService){
    // Resource example
    // { id: 1, title: 'Example', assignee_id: 1 }
    var Plan = $resource('/plans/:id', { id: '@id' }, { 
        'query':  { method:'GET', isArray: true },
        'get':  { method:'GET', isArray: false },
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });

    // Return the matching person from PeopleService
    Plan.prototype.assignee = function() {
        if(this.assignee_id) {
            return PeopleService.find_by_id(this.assignee_id)

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    return Plan;
});
```

**PeopleService**

```
angular.module('exampleApp')
.service('PeopleService', function($http, $q){

  var people_array = $q.defer();


  // This list is reasonably static hence why I feel no need to make it it's own resource
  // Contains an array of people objects for example 
  // { id: 1, name: 'Paul Smith', hourly_rate: 5.0, max_hours: 8 }
  $http.get('/people/json').then(function(result) {
   people_array.resolve(result.data);
  });

  this.all = function() {
    return people_array.promise;
  };

this.find_by_id = function(id) {

    var def = $q.defer();

    people_array.promise.then(function(data) {
      // underscore.js find
      var person = _.find(data, function(person) {
        return parseInt(person.id) === parseInt(id);
      })
      def.resolve(person);
    });

    return def.promise;
  };

});
```

**View**

```
<select name="person_id" class="form-control" ng-model="plan.assignee_id" ng-options="assignee.id as assignee.name for person in people" required>
</select>

{{ plan.assignee().name }}
```

Now the select populates no problem, however the **plan.assignee.name** causes the digest errors when using the select menu to select an option. I'm sure this is a misunderstanding I have with how promises work so I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.